# Always showing the emulator when running an application

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio, and I'm building a small android project.
I connected my phone to my laptop so that I could see the device real time debugs through the logcat in the Android Device Monitor.

However, when I run my project, it never shows up the device list for me to choose my phone, but always the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Edit Configuration]

Make sure you have this option selected as shown in the image attached. Once you've done this, ensure that your phone has the "USB debugging" enabled under Developer Options.

Answer (score 0):

Enable usb debugging in developer options in your android phone. And check running devices list in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On the left of the run button in the tool bar, there is a drop-down menu. Click it, then choose "Edit configurations". (Or, use the menu and select Run->Edit Configurations.) On the left of the window that appears, choose your application (often called "mobile"). On the right of the window, in the "Target device" section, press "Show chooser dialog." and uncheck "Use same device for future launches." Press OK and try to run again.

**Edit** I misread the question, sorry. I see that you are seeing the chooser dialog but don't see your phone. Try the following:

- On your device, make sure developer options are enabled. To do this, press Settings->About Phone then tap the build number several times. Then go back, and you will see the option "Developer Options". Press this, then enable USB debugging.
- Make sure you have installed the phone's driver if necessary.
- Some devices allow you to set whether to connect via USB as a media device or camera. The location of this setting varies by phone. Try setting it to camera, this is sometimes the issue.